# Rails: How to sort attribute array by associated attribute name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

How can I sort an array of person id's by Person.name derived from a Group model that has an has_many association with an Person model and goes through a GroupParticipation model?

`<OpenStruct id=1, name="GroupName", person_ids=[199, 276, 233, 214, 248, 252, 236]>`

**Person model:**

```
# Table name: people
#
#  id                          :integer          not null, primary key
#  name                        :string(255)
```

`has_many :groups, through: :group_participations, source: :person_group`

**Person::Group model:**

```
# Table name: person_groups
#
#  id                   :integer          not null, primary key
#  name                 :string(255)
#  details              :hstore
#  created_at           :datetime
#  updated_at           :datetime
#  show_job_description :boolean          default(FALSE)
```

`has_many :group_participations, foreign_key: "person_group_id"`

`has_many :people, through: :group_participations`

**Person::GroupParticipation model**

```
# Table name: person_group_participations
#
#  id                :integer          not null, primary key
#  person_group_id   :integer
#  person_id         :integer
#  created_at        :datetime
#  updated_at        :datetime
#  registration_date :date
#  expiry_date       :date
```

`belongs_to :person`
`belongs_to :person_group, class: Person::Group`

**ContactsController**

```
> def index
>     @groups = Person::Group.all
>     people_ids = @groups.map(&:person_ids).flatten
>     @people = Person.where(ids: people_ids)   
> end
```

**index.html.slim**

```
   - @groups.each do |group|
     h2 = group.name
     - group.person_ids.each do |id|
       - next if (person = @people.find{|p| p.id == id}).blank?

         details.full-width
         .name= person.name
```

Comment: So, basically, you want to order `Person` records by associated `Group` name?

Comment: Who are `people`?

Comment: I want to display the individual `Group` names with `Person` names ordered alphabetically under the group.

Comment: `People` is an association with person_id that `belongs_to :person`

Comment: I don't quite get it. One `Person` can have more than one group, right? So what exactly do you want to display?

Comment: @AndréHatlo-Johansen can you show a more complete example? With some person records, some group records (as tables maybe) and the expected result?

Comment: I'll try to explain. I have 4 groups which i am trying to display in the view. Under each group people get displayed in the order `person_ids` are stored in the array as seen. So for each new group member i add, it lists the persons as added. I cant find a way to sort the `person_ids` array so that it lists the persons alphabetically.

Comment: The id fiddling in the controller (and view) can be avoided by using [`includes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) or [`joins`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins). Maybe you can even move the sorting into the database but at least you can get the groups with their persons attached (which makes sorting a breeze).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try (assuming you have `@group`):

```
@group.people.order(name: :asc).pluck(:id)
```

To give you the array like `[199, 276, 233, 214, 248, 252, 236]`.

I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something, but why wouldn't you do something more like:

ContactsController

```
def index
  @groups = Person::Group.all
end
```

index.html.slim

```
- @groups.each do |group|
  h2 = group.name
  - group.people.order(name: :asc).each do |person|
    details.full-width
      .name= person.name
```

Apologies in advance if I messed up the `slim`, I'm a `haml` user myself.

Comment: Ugly N+1, why don't you use `includes`, or (probably even better) `eager_load`?

Comment: @MarekLipka Yeah, ok. Good point. I was more focused on the idea that the OP was doing a lot of very strange mechanics. This (directionally), makes more sense, don't you think? But, your point is very well taken. BTW, perhaps you might consider offering an answer.

Comment: Yup, the rest of your answer looks ok and indeed solves OP's problem, if I understood it correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure it will work properly after your change, I guess not (and it will still generate separate SQL query for each person), could you check it? I'm thinking more about something like this: `@groups = Person::Group.eager_load(:people).order('groups.name ASC, persons.name ASC')` and simply `group.people.each`... in view. That will generate big query with left join that will sort all of this stuff together.

Comment: Your right, it doesn't seem to work. Your query looks like something that would work, but unfortunately its returning `PG::UndefinedTable: Error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "person"`.

Comment: @AndréHatlo-Johansen yeah, sorry, I didn't notice the name of the table you're holding your people in. Try then `@groups = Person::Group.eager_load(:people).order('groups.name ASC, people.name ASC')` obviously.